# xp20:add-daytime returning FOTY0001 error message

Tags: oracle, xpath, bpel

xp20:add-dayTimeDuration-to-dateTime(string(bpws:getVariableData 
('Eligibility_Out','payload','/ns3:response/ns3:AcctEffDt')), string('P7D'))

I am using the above expression in a BPEL Process to add 7 days to a date which has the format of yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00+00.

If there is no time element to the date the expression works in the unit tests, but because the data is coming from another application it has this time element. However, there is no time to in the date. Unfortunately, when the expression fails with FOTY0001 error message.

I have not been able to find a solution online and I am asking if anyone can help?

Comment: What namespace URI is the prefix xp20 bound to?

Comment: Uses the xp namespace

Comment: What is that supposed to mean? Please look for a namespace declaration of the form `xmlns:xp20="some-namespace-uri"` and tell us what `some-namespace-uri` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. It didn't like finding the value and manipulating the value at the same time. So I broke it into two steps